# split string into words in C

Tags: c, string

I have just coded splitting string into words.

if char *cmd = "Hello world baby", then argv[0] = "Hello", argv[1] = "world", argv[2] = "baby".

strdup function cannot be used, and I want to implement this using malloc and strcpy.

my code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define buf_size 128

int main() {
    
    char *argv[16];
    memset(argv, 0, sizeof(argv));
    int words = 0;

    char *cmd = "Hello world baby";
    unsigned int len = strlen(cmd);
    int start = 0;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= len; i++){
        if(cmd[i] == ' ' | cmd[i] == '\0'){
            ++words;
            char *w = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(i-start) + 1);
            strcpy(w, cmd + start);
            w[i-start] = '\0';
            argv[i] = w;
            start = i + 1;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < words; i++){
    printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    free(argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I hoped that the `printf` function produces:

```
Hello
world
baby
```

However, when the `printf()` function is reached, the program triggers a segmentation fault.

Comment: Can't use `strdup`? Write your own: `char * my_strdup(const char *src) { size_t len = strlen(src); char *buf = malloc(len + 1); strcpy(buf,src); return buf; }` That's legal, based on your assignment. And, recommended. Suppose you had to do this in _multiple_ places. Everybody would suggest creating a function to eliminate code replication (i.e. DRY--don't repeat yourself).

Comment: You must use a different index for the `argv`. For instance, `int j = 0;` and replace `argv[i] = w` with `argv[j++] = w` after checking for `j < 16`. Also replace the `|` with `||`.

Comment: What @CraigEstey said except that the code ***must*** check that the allocation worked — `char * my_strdup(const char *src) { size_t len = strlen(src); char *buf = malloc(len + 1); if (buf != NULL) strcpy(buf,src); return buf; }` — you can choose how to write the test, but you must test the result of `malloc()` before using it. There's a chance that `memmove(buf, src, len + 1);` will be quicker than `strcpy()` — it doesn't have to test each byte as it progresses. And you can use `memcpy()` instead of `memmove()` here, but I use `memmove()` because it is always correct and `memcpy()` isn't.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I realized that [at 6 minutes]. I was too lazy to fix it with another comment. But, then I thought "an exercise". But, OP didn't respond. It's slightly faster to use `memcpy`, so, hopefully, I acquit myself with: `char * my_strdup(const char *src) { size_t len = strlen(src) + 1; char *buf = malloc(len); if (buf != NULL) memcpy(buf,src,len); return buf; }`

Comment: @CraigEstey — that saves a `+ 1` that I didn't optimize out.  Let's call it quits (even-stevens).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your primary problem, despite the banter in the comments about how to write your own version of `strdup()`, is that you really need `strndup()`.  Eh?

You have the line:

```
strcpy(w, cmd + start);
```

Unfortunately, this copies the whole string from `cmd + start` into the allocated space, but you only wanted to copy `(i - start) + 1` bytes including the null byte, because that's all the space you allocated.  So, you have a buffer overflow (but not a stack overflow).

POSIX provides the function [`strndup()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strndup.html)
with the signature:

```
extern char *strndup(const char *s, size_t size);
```

This allocates at most `size + 1` bytes and copies at most `size` bytes from `s` and a null byte into the allocated space.  You'd use:

```
argv[i] = strndup(cmd + start, i - start);
```

to get the required result.  If you don't have (or can't use) `strndup()`, you can write your own.  That's easiest if you have [`strnlen()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strnlen.html), but you can write your own version of that if necessary (you don't have it or can't use it):

```
char *my_strndup(const char *s, size_t len)
{
    size_t nbytes = strnlen(s, len);
    char *result = malloc(nbytes + 1);
    if (result != NULL)
    {
        memmove(result, s, nbytes);
        result[nbytes] = '\0';
    }
    return result;
}
```

This deals with the situation where the actual string is shorter than the maximum length it can be by using the size from `strnlen()`.  It's not clear that you are guaranteed to be able to access the memory at `s + nbytes - 1`, so simply allocating for the maximum size is not appropriate.

Implementing `strnlen()`:

```
size_t my_strnlen(const char *s, size_t size)
{
    size_t count = 0;
    while (count < size && *s++ != '\0')
        count++;
    return count;
}
```

"Official" versions of this are probably implemented in assembler and are more efficient, but I think that's a valid implementation in pure C.

Another alternative in your code is to use the knowledge of the length:

```
            char *w = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(i - start + 1));
            memmove(w, cmd + start, i - start);
            w[i-start] = '\0';
            argv[i] = w;
            start = i + 1;
```

I note in passing that multiplying by `sizeof(char)` is a no-op since `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition.  You should include the `+ 1` in the multiplication in general (as I've reparenthesized the expression). If you were dealing with some structure and wanted N + 1 structures, you need to use `(N + 1) * sizeof(struct WhatNot)` and not `N * sizeof(struct WhatNot) + 1`.  It's a good idea to head off bugs caused by sloppy coding practices while you're learning, even though there's no difference in the result here.

There are those who [excoriate the cast on the result of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).  I'm not one of them: I learned to program on a pre-standard C system where the cast was crucial because the `char *` address of an object was different from the address of the same memory location when referenced via a pointer to a type bigger than a `char`.  That is, the `short *` address and `char *` address for the same memory location had different bit patterns.  Not casting the result of `malloc()` led to crashes.  (I observe that the primary excuse given for rejecting the cast is "it may hide errors if `malloc()` is not declared".  That excuse went by the wayside when C99 mandated that functions must be declared before being used.)

<sup>*Warning: no compiler was consulted about the validity of any of the code shown in this answer.  Nor was the sanity of the overall algorithm tested.*</sup>

You have:

```
if(cmd[i] == ' ' | cmd[i] == '\0'){
```

That `|` should be `||`.